# How to change activity, when app is in the background

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have an application, that should run some loading (I/O operations) before switching to other activity, that will display loaded information. I would like to load information completly, before switching and this causes some design troubles. I might could have used `AsyncTask` to run stuff in the background, but from the design perspective I dont want the whole context of the Application be leaked in order to respond to the results. The concept of `Service` looks more likely to fit my needs.

So let me denote the situation I can't solve from design perspective. Application starts, which causes some Activity to be created and so on. This one creates a service, which does I/O operations in the background. Upon finishing it, Application changes the Activity to the specified one. The question is, how should I handle the situation, when service finishes it's job while the app is in background. As a programmer, I would like to make my app either reopen the first activity and insta change to the following one or simply start with the "following" one. Any ideas?

Comment: You can start the desired activity from your service.

Comment: Shall activity pop up instantly, or when the user returns back to the app? The first option is not desired.

Comment: If you start from the service it would pop up immediately.

Comment: I have added a solution for the case where you want to open the new activity only when user opens up the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to make my app either reopen the first activity and insta change to the following one

You could this. When processing in your service finishes save a value in `SharedPreference` like this

```
Context ctx = getApplicationContext();
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("LoadNewActivity", true); // or false
editor.commit();
```

Now do this in your launcher activity `onCreate()`

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
boolean loadNewActivity = prefs.getBoolean("LoadNewActivity", false);
if(loadNewActivity) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyNewActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
else 
{
    // Do normal startup
}
```

Comment: Some solutions are easier, than you can imagine. Thanks.

Comment: Well, according to the fact, that I/O operations are in common a bad practise at the main thread(and writing to preferences is one), I am unsatisfied atm. I use static field for the same purpose. I am trying to find a better solution.